# EWS SOAP Requests failing

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl, exchangewebservices, soaplite

I am using PERL and SOAP::Lite to make soap calls to MS Exchange Web Services. I have already figured out authenticating and am using an Oauth token to make the calls. I am trying to call GetInboxRules which is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff709501(v=exchg.150).aspx).

Basically the call needs to look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
        xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP1" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetInboxRules>
      <m:MailboxSmtpAddress>User1@Contoso.com</m:MailboxSmtpAddress>
    </m:GetInboxRules>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My first attempt used the following code:

```
my $client = SOAP::Lite->service('file://home/auth/work/src/ben/services.wsdl')->proxy('https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx');
$client->readable(1)->autotype(0)->outputxml('true');
$client->ns('http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages', 'm');

my $ua = $client->schema->useragent;
$ua->default_header('Authorization' => $auth_header);
$ua->default_header('Content-Type' => 'application/xml');
$client->schema->useragent($ua);

$client->transport->http_request->headers->push_header('Authorization'=> $auth_header);

# WITH URI
my $som = $client->call('GetInboxRules', SOAP::Data->name('MailboxSmtpAddress')->value('eg7636@foo.com')->uri('http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'));
```

This produced the following XML along with a 500 internal server error stating:

"The request failed schema validation: The element 'GetInboxRules' in namespace  'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages' has invalid child element 'MailboxSmtpAddress'. List of possible elements expected: 'MailboxSmtpAddress' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetInboxRules>
      <MailboxSmtpAddress>eg7636@foo.com</MailboxSmtpAddress>
    </m:GetInboxRules>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am already setting the name space but to try and remedy this I specified the names space for the MailboxSmtpAddress element by adding a uri specification to it `my $som = $client->call('GetInboxRules', SOAP::Data->name('MailboxSmtpAddress')->value('eg7636@foo.com')->uri('http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'));`

which produced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    soap:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:namesp3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetInboxRules>
      <namesp3:MailboxSmtpAddress xmlns:namesp3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">eg7636@foo.com</namesp3:MailboxSmtpAddress>
    </m:GetInboxRules>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

followed by a 400 Bad Request response. I am guessing that the bad request response is because of the url included in the MailboxSmtpAddress tag but I don't know how else to specify the namespace.

This is my first time working with SOAP so any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A saint came to my rescue and presented me with the following code:

```
my $client = SOAP::Lite
    ->readable(1)
    ->proxy('https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx')
    ->ns( 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types', 'typ')
    ->ns( 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages', 'mes')
    ->envprefix('soapenv')
    ->autotype(0);

$client->serializer->{'_attr'}{'{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}encodingStyle'} = undef;


$client->transport->default_header('Authorization' => $auth_header);
$client->transport->default_header('X-AnchorMailbox' => 'eg7636@foo.onmicrosoft.com');
$client->transport->default_header('X-OWA-ExplicitLogonUser' => 'eg7636@foo.onmicrosoft.com');

my @header = (
    SOAP::Header->name('typ:RequestServerVersion')->attr({'Version' => 'Exchange2015'}),
    SOAP::Header->name('typ:ExchangeImpersonation')->value(\SOAP::Header->name('typ:ConnectingSID')
        ->value(\SOAP::Header->name('typ:SmtpAddress')->value('eg7636@foo.com')))
);

my @param;
my $method;

@param = (
     SOAP::Data->name('mes:MailboxSmtpAddress', 'eg7636@foo.com'),
     );

$method = SOAP::Data->name('mes:GetInboxRules');

my $response = $client->call($method => (@param, @header));

print Dumper($response);
```

This resulted in the namespace tag being placed on the elements being passed to the method call and also corrected some issues I had with the formatting of the header.

The following is the XML that came from that code:

```
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:mes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:typ="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <typ:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2015" />

    <typ:ExchangeImpersonation>
      <typ:ConnectingSID>
        <typ:SmtpAddress>eg7636@foo.com</typ:SmtpAddress>
      </typ:ConnectingSID>
    </typ:ExchangeImpersonation>
  </soapenv:Header>

  <soapenv:Body>
    <mes:GetInboxRules>
      <mes:MailboxSmtpAddress>eg7636@foo.com</mes:MailboxSmtpAddress>
    </mes:GetInboxRules>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This produced a successful response from Microsoft.